In Cpp how to specify a different constructor based on using `{}` vs `()`
I am learning Cpp so apologies if I've not used correct terminology.
As a point of reference the constructors for the vector class have different behaviour dependent on whether the object was initialised with {} or () e.g.
    std::vector<int> v1{5};  // Produces {5}
    std::vector<int> v2(5);  // Produces {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Is there a term for this difference and how can you implement similar functionality in your own classes ?

This second syntax is "uniform initialization" and is anything but uniform.  Here is a great video to watch about all of the issues: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Be warned that this is considered by many an unfortunate emergent property of std::vector due to poorly thought out design. I wouldn't recommend replicating it.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica At least it's not as bad as the JavaScript Array constructor, which has a discontinuity at argc==1.

As a curiosity(?), you can also write std::vector<int> v[5]; to create an array of 5 vectors. Typography is important!

Also try std::vector<std::string> v1 {5}; to get another surprise.  :-)
